# R documentation: the @family tag is not working

Tags: r, roxygen2

I'm writing an R package, and I'd like to include cross references between function documentation.

Following the documentation [here](https://roxygen2.r-lib.org/articles/rd.html), there's a setion that talks specifically about this:

> #### Cross-references
>
> There are two tags that make it easier for people to navigate around your documentation: `@seealso` and `@family`. [...] If you have a family of related functions, you can use `@family {family}` to cross-reference each function to every other function within the family. A function can be a member of multiple families.
>
> For `sum()`, this might look like:
>
> ```
> #' @family aggregations
> #' @seealso [prod()] for products, [cumsum()] for cumulative sums, and
> #'   [colSums()]/[rowSums()] marginal sums over high-dimensional arrays.
> ```
>
> By default `@family {family}`, will generate the see also text `“Other {family}:”`, so the `@family` name should be plural (i.e., `“model building helpers”` not `“model building helper”`). You can override the default title by providing a `rd_family_title` list in `man/roxygen/meta.R`:
>
> ```
> rd_family_title <- list(
>  aggregations = "Aggregation functions"
> )
> ```

So, I've written the documentation of my functions like this:

```
#' My foo function
#'
#' Does something with my data.
#'
#' Lorem ipsum.
#'
#' @param .data A data frame.
#' @return My processed data.
#' @usage
#' my_foo_function(.data)
#' @family {a_family}
#' @family {another_family}
#' @export
my_foo_function <- function(.data) {
# Some code
}
```

(there are about 9 functions I've written this way)

I've also written this `meta.R` file:

```
rd_family_title <- list(
  a_family = "A family of functions",
  another_family = "Another family of functions"
)
```

This is saved here: `[package project path]/roxygen/man/meta.R` (again, following the documentation).

However, when I run the `document()` function (to build the `.Rd` files), I get the following warnings:

```
document()
## Updating my_package documentation
## Writing NAMESPACE
## Warning messages:
## 1: Unknown Roxygen options a_family, another_family.
## Supported options: roclets, load, old_usage, markdown, r6, package
```

And, when browsing the documentation, I see something like this:

> [...]
>
> #### See also
>
> Other a_family: bar(), baz()
>   Other another_family: spam(), eggs()

(I've changed `@family {a_family}` with `@family a_family` and I get the same result.

So... What am I missing? Where should the `rd_family_title` list be? Why is Roxygen failing to replace that "other..." stuff with the titles I've defined?

---

Some aditional info:

- R version: 3.6.0, running on CentOs 7, and using Rstudio
- Roxygen2 version: 7.0.2
- devtools version: 2.2.1

Comment: `man/roxygen/meta.R` should return a list, of which one element is `rd_family_title`, see [here](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/pull/883/files#diff-8312ad0561ef661716b48d09478362f3R3). That should remove the warning. Still doesn't work for me though

Comment: Actually I'm wrong, I simply had `<-` rather than `=` when making the list. It seems this may currently be broken, since `load_options_meta` is only done globally and `rd_family_title` is not an allowed option, see: https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/search?q=load_options_meta&unscoped_q=load_options_meta

Comment: @alanocallaghan Thank you... It looks broken :( it's sad, it would have been great if it worked

Comment: I'd suggest opening an issue on the repo, either it'll get fixed or they'll tell you what you're doing wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `man/roxygen/meta.R` example in the documentation was wrong at the time when you consulted it. The first list level was missing.

In your case it should be:

```r
list(
  rd_family_title = list(a_family = "A family of functions",
                         another_family = "Another family of functions")
)
```

There was also an omission in the code that prevented roxygen2's `rd_family_title` option from being recognized. All these issues have been fixed in [PR 1078](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/pull/1078) which is included from [roxygen2 7.1.1](https://github.com/r-lib/roxygen2/releases/tag/v7.1.1) onwards.

Comment: Thanks. I'll test it soon

Comment: @Barranka Have you been able to test it? If so, would you be so kind to mark my answer as _solving_ your question (the green checkmark)?

Comment: I've had no opportunity to test this (work issues). As soon as I can I'll test it and mark this as the accepted answer